# Attempt to use invalid handle -1 in Kodi

Tags: python, kodi

I am learning Python through the development of a Kodi add-on. I am trying to display an image using the `xbmcplugin.setResolvedUrl()` function but I get an error:

> 'Attempt to use invalid handle -1' error.

I am get rid of the error when including `li.setProperty("IsPlayable", "true")` in my `addFile` function **but then the image is not displayed**.

What am I doing wrong?

My code:

```
import sys
import urllib
import urlparse
import xbmcgui
import xbmcplugin
import xbmcaddon

my_addon = xbmcaddon.Addon()
addon_path = xbmc.translatePath(my_addon.getAddonInfo('path'))
base_url = sys.argv[0]
addon_handle = int(sys.argv[1])
args = urlparse.parse_qs(sys.argv[2][1:])
mode = args.get('mode', None)

def build_url(query):
    return base_url + '?' + urllib.urlencode(query)

def addFile(filename, filepath):
    filedir = build_url({'mode': 'display', 'filepath': filepath})
    li = xbmcgui.ListItem(filename)
    xbmcplugin.addDirectoryItem(handle=addon_handle, url=filedir, listitem=li)

def displayImage(url):
    li = xbmcgui.ListItem('Sample image')
    li.setPath(url)
    xbmcplugin.setResolvedUrl(addon_handle, True, listitem=li)
    xbmc.log('Display image...',level=xbmc.LOGNOTICE)

if mode is None:
    fileurl = 'https://elmicrolector.files.wordpress.com/2016/10/breu-14-a1.jpg'
    addFile('Sample image', fileurl)
    xbmcplugin.setContent(addon_handle, 'files')
    xbmcplugin.endOfDirectory(addon_handle)

elif mode[0] == 'display':
    displayImage(args['filepath'][0])
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out the xbmcplugin.setResolvedUrl() function can only be used with videos, not with images.